# How to import recorded iPhone gyro data into blender?

Tags: python, import, coordinates

I recorded iPhone's rotation and now I want to import these data as x,y,z for object rotation in blender.

How can I convert OSC or CSV formats into F-Curves?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I found add-on csv_fcurve_importer that I can't activate even in 2.57, that was written for. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?209181-A-Script-to-Import-a-CSV-File-and-Create-F-Curves-(for-Blender-2-5x-or-later)

Comment: if you provide a sample of the CSV file it would be easy to see what can be done with the data. maybe a custom importer. OSC messages are easy to deal with but unless they include time stamps they can be less accurate depending on what is used to transport the data UDP or whatever. I recommend a CSV file.

Comment: I used app SensorLog https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sensorlog/id388014573?mt=8 that gives me this output file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55113627/%3E%20Blender/2015-04-20_16-16-10.csv This is just sample, in my case I need synchronized live footage with CG - finger that rotate with circle in z axis. But it would be awesome to be able convert any CSV data to f-curves.

Comment: The autthor of that CSV importer responded to you on BA, with any luck he can sort it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download [SensorLog](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sensorlog/id388014573?mt=8) app for your mobile device (free) and record some motion. Data can be send from device via mail or you can connect to local network. Output format is CSV.
2. Download add-on [csv_fcurve_importer](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?209181-A-Script-to-Import-a-CSV-File-and-Create-F-Curves-(for-Blender-2-5x-or-later)) to import csv data.
   Addon appear in Scene properties window.
   (Works for blender 2.74)

Thanks to zeffii's comment about OSC vs. CSV formats.