# Creating multiple curves from CSV

Tags: bezier-curves, csv

I have a CSV file that contains XYZ points for many separate curves. It is formatted like this

x  y  z  curve ID 
 1  2  3  aB12 
 7  8  9  aB13 
 8  10  40  aB12 
 1  3  6  aB13

I'm looking for a way to import these points and form them into individual curves based on their curve id. I have over 200 curves, so importing them individually would be quite time consuming.

Comment: This is probably quite doable but will likely require a script using the Blender Python API. Certainly you are not expecting anyone here to write it for you.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71458/how-to-read-a-csv-file-and-use-the-values-as-x-and-y-points-in-blender/71466#71466 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28690/how-to-import-recorded-iphone-gyro-data-into-blender/28796#28796 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35945/python-script-to-read-in-csv-file-containing-quaternion-coordinates-and-turn-it and [many many more](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=csv)