# Represent temperature by colors over time

Tags: animation, color, csv, spreadsheet

I want to represent the temperatures of zones in my building by colors over time.
I have a file that has the following form :

| Time | T_zone1 | T_zone2 | T_zoneN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 20. | 21. | 20. |
| 2. | 19. | 22. | 21. |
| 3. | 18. | 17. | 10. |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can i do this ? Supposed that i presented the zones by cubes in Blender ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use addon import csv as fcurves https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28796/2214 and use them to animate shader ... I didn't test it now, I'm not sure if there is an update.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using lights and in shader editor, use a blackbody node to control the heat emission for particular cubes.

Comment: I think his problem is how to get the values from the file into the model without doing it manually, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

*This is more like general idea "How to ..." than best solution.*

There is an add-on [csv_fcurve_importer](https://github.com/ProtoxiDe22/Blender-csv-fcurve-importer) (works for me at Blender 3.x versions). With that you can import data as f-curves ... and use these f-curves as keyframes for *Value* node of material node-tree.

Example of your CSV, assigned to *Location* ...
[image]

Since I  need f-curve for *Value* node in shader I wanted to assign data to *Value* node via addon, but even *Data path* field comment says "... right click when hovering above text and choose *Copy Data Path*, pasting it to *Data Path* field the generated f-curve is still *Action* data block.

So ... I had to manually copy/paste f-curve to Value node ...

[image]
[image]

In this material example I used *Map Range* node to set the Coolest color (Blue in Coloramp) at value 10 and the Warmest color (Red in Coloramp) at value 30 ...

[image]

I don't have scripting knowledge, but for someone who knows sounds to me easy to assign CSV values to shader.

Or you can use location info (or other keyframe accessible from UI) as driver for color change (that is also copy/paste, but since done once on some proxy object you don't have to repeat this process when CSV data change).