# How can I export phone sensor information to Blender?

Tags: tracking

**In short: video tracking using Android 11 smartphone sensors, without using tracking markers.**

I need to export movement information from android sensors to a program. Can this be done with addons or third party programs? I've seen several questions about this topic, but they either didn't have an answer or didn't have a solution.

There is no solution to the question!

Comment: Could you provide more context about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Probably related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28690